Google Script Error - "The state token is invalid or has expired. Please try again."
I've been struggling with an OAuth2 authorization error in my Google Apps Script for a couple of weeks. I'm trying to allow multiple Google accounts to authorize the script, but I keep encountering a "State token mismatch" error. Here's the relevant code I'm using:
var OAUTH2_LIBRARY_KEY = '1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF';

const CLIENT_ID_PROPERTY = 'OAUTH_CLIENT_ID';
const CLIENT_SECRET_PROPERTY = 'OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET';
const REDIRECT_URI = 'https://script.google.com/macros/d/your-deployment-id/usercallback'; 
const SPREADSHEET_ID = 'my-spreadsheet-id';
const SHEET_NAME = 'Authorized Users';

const CLIENT_ID = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(CLIENT_ID_PROPERTY);
const CLIENT_SECRET = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(CLIENT_SECRET_PROPERTY);

if (!CLIENT_ID || !CLIENT_SECRET) {
  throw new Error('Client ID and/or Client Secret are not set in script properties.');
}

function createOAuthService(stateToken = null) {
  const scopes = [
    'removed the scopes as it looks spammy to github as they are urls'
  ];
  
  const authuserParam = '0';

  const service = OAuth2.createService('Google')
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth')
    .setTokenUrl('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token')
    .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
    .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
    .setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI)
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    .setScope(scopes.join(' '))
    .setParam('access_type', 'offline')
    .setParam('authuser', authuserParam)
    .setParam('approval_prompt', 'force');

  if (stateToken) {
    service.setParam('state', stateToken);
  }

  Logger.log('OAuth Scopes: ' + scopes.join(', '));
  Logger.log('OAuth Service Created.');
  
  return service;
}

function authCallback(request) {
  Logger.log('authCallback invoked');
  Logger.log('Request Object: ' + JSON.stringify(request));

  const storedStateToken = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty('OAUTH2_STATE');
  const receivedStateToken = request.parameter.state;

  if (storedStateToken !== receivedStateToken) {
    Logger.log('State token mismatch. Possible CSRF attack.');
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Authorization failed. State token mismatch. Please try again.');
  }

  const service = createOAuthService();
  
  let authorized;
  try {
    authorized = service.handleCallback(request);
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log('Error handling callback: ' + e.message);
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Authorization failed. Error handling callback: ' + e.message);
  }

  if (authorized) {
    logAuthorizedUser();
    Logger.log('Authorization successful.');
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Authorization successful. You can close this window.');
  } else {
    Logger.log('Authorization failed.');
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Authorization failed. Please try again.');
  }
}


The issue arises during the callback function, where I get a "State token mismatch" error. The user is not able to complete the authorization process successfully.
What I’ve tried:

Verifying the OAuth consent screen settings in Google Cloud.
Ensuring that the correct scopes are set.
Testing with different Google accounts.
I have

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

You can try these -

Ensure you are using an updated version of the OAuth2 library.
Test the flow in different environments to rule out caching issues.
Pass the state token in the OAuth request and validate it during the callback


You don't state in your question but I assume (!?) you're using apps-script-oauth2. There are several issues that include the state token including this comment that may be relevant.

Thank you for your suggestions. 1. Using the latest OAuth Library 43. Tried it in different browsers, including incgognito modes. 3. Not sure how to do this to be honest.
